# I am trying to calculate % decimal(flotant) of a num X but I don't know how to do it

Tags: haskell

I am trying to calculate % decimal(flotant) of a num X
but I don't know how to do it.

```
pourcentage :: Int -> Int -> Float 

pourcentage 20 100 = 20 
pourcentage n m = ( 
    fromIntegral n * fromIntegral m
    ) / 100
```

But I know how to do it in integer values without decimals.

Comment: Please edit the question to have a title in English (otherwise it’ll get closed)

Comment: If you have floating-point arguments, you don't need `fromIntegral` at all. The division operator (/) will be able to operate on the arguments directly.

Answer (score 0):

Formula of percentage is partOfSomething / totalSomething * 100.

Let's just rewrite it in haskell:

```
percentage partOfSomething totalSomething = partOfSomething / totalSomething * 100
```

Shorten variable names:

```
percentage n m = n / m * 100
```

Specify type of this function:

```
percentage :: Float -> Float -> Float
percentage n m = n / m * 100
```

And finally generalise it:

```
percentage :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
percentage n m = n / m * 100
```